# Backbone.js: what is "model" inside "render: function(model){...}"?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm asking this based on a blog I read...

[backbone.js simple inheritance...](http://jcreamerlive.com/2011/11/17/backbonejs-simple-inheritance-first-run/#comment-328)

Where does the parameter **model** come from in `render: function(model){...}`? I know that `this.render` is called for every new item within the collection, but where does function(**model**) come from? And how can that be passed as model for SingleAnimalView like so: `new SingleAnimalView({model: model})`?

```
var AnimalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#demo",
    initialize: function(){
        window.animals.bind("add", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(model){
        var singleAnimalView = new SingleAnimalView({model: model});
        $(this.el).append(singleAnimalView.el);
    }
});
```

**Here's the jsFiddle link**: http://jsfiddle.net/HVK7F/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `add` event is fired from the `animals` collection, the callback method's first argument will be item that was added to the collection.

In this case, `render(model)` is being used as the event handler, and model will be the item added.

Have a look at the [`add` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-73) of the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) to see how it's invoked. Ultimately it's a result of this line:

```
if (!options.silent) model.trigger('add', model, this, options);
```

[`trigger()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-16) takes all of the arguments except the first one and passes them to the callback.